# Decremental for loop in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to increment date in python using predefined functions in my environment. The brute force way of doing this looks as such:

```
T=date() - ONE
print(T)
T=(date() - ONE) - ONE
print(T)
```

date() and ONE are pre-defined functions in an env that cannot be manipulated.
How do I create a loop to repeatedly decrement date() 100 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a for loop! You can use this for more reference (https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) but a simple solution would just be:

```
for x in range(100):
      T -= date() - ONE
```

Comment: `T = T - date() - ONE` perhaps ?

Comment: so the for loop shown above keeps printing the same date (date function is sys generated today's date). date()-ONE prints yesterday's date. I want to go back 100 days

Comment: @ravecoder the new edit should be correct, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You can use timedelta for this

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
today = datetime.today()
for i in range(100):
    new_date = today - timedelta(days=i)
    print(new_date)
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-datetime-timedelta-function/